# Zooming and TapGesture in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to add zooming (using pinch gesture) and touch (using tapGesture) in UIImageView without using scrollView? Is it possible? I have used both UIImageView and UIScrollView.This is my code placed on viewDidLoad.

```
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 12.0;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.userInteractionEnabled];
    [[self view] addSubview:imgView];

    [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:self.view];



//gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

If I try this code.Works fine with Tap but zooming doesn't work because Imageview hides scrollview.Is there any idea, How to add both zooming and touch functionality on UIImageview?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to add both zooming and tap gestures on uiimage view just see [this code](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture) i have found on net this will help you with what you need.
Enjoy Codding ;)

Comment: @Alok.I have one more issue.Issue is that I have UIViews (like a GRID) in my app. When I ZoomIn ImageView,grid will also zoomed in. I don't want that. I mean when I zoom ImageView, SubViews should not be zoom. Any Idea..?

Comment: for that i think you have to apply all zooming effects on the imageView only i mean connect gestures to the imageview only